# TOR 7.5 starts then immediately crashes windows 10

Tags: error

Tor auto updated. Then when opened it I got: "Unable to start Tor. Failed to get hashed password."

I made a copy of my bookmarkbackups folder, deleted the tor browser folder and did a clean install of tor 7.5 and then it would start and immediately crash.

I deleted the tor browser folder again and installed Version 7.0.10 and turned off automatic updating.

Win 10x64 pro Version 18299.192

Comment: I'll make a bet that this is caused by your anti-virus. It's almost always the case, antivirus, trusteer, etc always break Tor Browser on updates because the code they inject into Tor Browser to spy on what you're using it for and report it back to the companies isn't expecting the new Tor Browser version.

Answer (score 0):

It was indeed my anti-virus software.

After running into the "blank screen never loading" problem with FF58 which requires one to disable identity protection I came back to this to find Webroot was blocking libssp-0.dll.

Simply changing it to protected fixed the issue. (Unlike FF58 where you must allow them to "extract personal information without your knowledge")